# CNAME for redirected Subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, 301-redirect, a-record

I have a domain `domain.com` where an A record for `my-sub` is set and a 301 redirect for `my-sub.domain.com` to `my-sub.notmydomain.com`. Now I got an information to set a new CNAME for `my-sub.domain.com` with name and value which look examplarily as follows:

```
"Name: _abcdefg123456.my-sub.domain.com.",
"Type: CNAME",
"Value: 7891011.abcdefg.hij-klm.xyz."
```

All the A records for subdomains are set without the domain itself, so the A record for `my-sub.domain.com` appears as `my-sub` within the domain `domain.com`. When setting up the CNAME, do I also have to set only `_abcdefg123456` as key or must be the key `_abcdefg123456.my-sub.domain.com.`?

Comment: It will help to explain what management system you are using to setup DNS. Or what  service you are using. I would assume you will need to set `_abcdefg123456.my-sub` though.

Comment: @akostadinov yes. semplon helped me already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is how it should be

**_abcdefg123456.my-sub** CNAME **7891011.abcdefg.hij-klm.xyz.**